# Get all childrens by parent. Recursion. MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that shows me all the parents of the child. But I would do it the other way, which is to display all the childrens for the parent.

This is my query for show all parents:

```
   SELECT T2.category_id ,T2.category_name
   FROM (
      SELECT
         @r AS _id,
         (SELECT @r := parent FROM categories WHERE category_id = _id) AS parent,
         @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
      FROM
          (SELECT @r := 1, @l := 0) vars,
          categories m
      WHERE @r <> 0) T1
      JOIN categories T2 ON T1._id = T2.category_id
      ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```

My db structure is only:
category_id | category_name | parent

and can not be changed.

How to display all the childrens by parent recursively?

Comment: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: i dont see any php in your codez

Comment: Maybe it can be solved after the php, so tag.

Comment: @deceze you read my question (structure and can not be changed)? Or paste link and go to the next questions?

Comment: Yes, I read your question. That article shows ways to do what you want though, and it also shows that doing it with the structure you have is difficult and that you *should* change the structure if at all possible.

Comment: You might get more traction on dba.stackexchange.com